# Load custom error htmlString when WKWebView loadRequest fails

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my controller I have a call to WKWebViewInstance.loadRequest(url). If there is no internet available, I want to load an error message in the WKWebView.

I have found that

```
  func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError)
```

gets called when a WKWEbView navigation fails with no internet connection. When I make the webView.loadHtmlString() call inside the above delegate method, nothing happens.

How do I detect the absence of network connection while WKWEbView navigation request is made and load a fixed error message into web view instead?

My delegate method code is

```
   func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    webView.stopLoading()
    webView.loadHTMLString(Constants.OfflineHtmlString!,baseURL:  nil)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

IF the need is to display error Info to the user when not connected to internet,

You can check if you are connected to the internet even before loading the request; `Reachability` is a popular api that usually helps checking this. There seems to be a swift port of it here https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

I recommend to pursue the above option; In case you still want to allow it to fail and then display the error, Ensure the correctness of your `OfflineHtmlString` and verify the error code before loading the `OfflineHtmlString`;

I don't know if your html string is valid; Provided it is valid, i would do something like below;

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
   if(error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet){
       webView.loadHTMLString(Constants.OfflineHtmlString!,baseURL:  nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to display an error message for any failure ( not just absence of internet). I should have mentioned that in question. calling loadHTMLString in didFailProvisionalNavigation results in a no-op for me. The code is executed but nothing happens. I tried to stop the current loading of webView before loadHTMLString call, but still same result

Answer (score 2):

Subbu is correct
just for swift4

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print("loading error", error)
    if(error._code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet){
        loadingLabel.text = "Hit Cancel to return back"
    }
    errorDisplay(error: "Loading error. Please try again later.\(error)")
    spinner.stopAnimating()
    loadingLabel.text = "Hit Cancel to return back"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `loadingHTMLString` won't work if you don't set the `baseURL`. If you don't have a valid URL you can use a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

This is what worked for me:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    if let urlError = error as? URLError {
        webView.loadHTMLString(urlError.localizedDescription, baseURL: urlError.failingURL)
    } else {
        webView.loadHTMLString(error.localizedDescription, baseURL: URL(string: "data:text/html"))
    }
}
```