# Show errors in Xamarin iOS WebView

Tags: xamarin

The Xamarin Forms WebView control shows a white surface if connection fails. On iOS, I want to show any error information I can get.

I am using this code to override WkWebViewRenderer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have also found this post which is now obsolete:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175060/how-can-i-display-a-detailed-error-code-retuned-from-a-webview?

How do I handle LoadFailed/Connection errors and display them to the user with WkWebViewRenderer?

Answer (score 2):

For **WkWebViewRenderer** we need to implement the **WKNavigationDelegate**

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer, IWKScriptMessageHandler 
{
    public HybridWebViewRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.NewElement!=null)
        {
            this.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate();
        }

    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{

    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWebpagePreferences preferences, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences> decisionHandler)
    {
      //  base.DecidePolicy(webView, navigationAction, preferences, decisionHandler);

        decisionHandler.Invoke(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow, preferences);

    }

    public override void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
    {
        base.DidFailNavigation(webView, navigation, error);

        //...load fail

    }

    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);

        //...load success
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to output the error with this line:
 webView.LoadHtmlString("<html><body><p>Error: " + error.ToString() + "</p></body></html>", null); 
but I still get a white surface

Comment: Where did you place the line code? Try detecting the status of the error to call the command. Check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703256/11083277

Comment: @Rugbrød Does it work now? Or you can share your sample to github so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: I don't know if it works. I have a different problem where the WebView won't show any URLs at all...

Comment: Could you share your project to github and I will check it .